# Firebase cloud functions incorrect header check

Tags: node.js, firebase, webhooks, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to receive a call to the Firebase Cloud Function and previously I was able to GET, but now I am unable to POST:

```
body:
<some valid json>

headers:
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1296
Content-Type: application/json
User-Agent: python-requests/2.9.1
```

this is what I see in the firebase log

> Error: incorrect header check at Zlib._handle.onerror (zlib.js:370:17)

I also see this:

> Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and
>   quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these
>   restrictions

I made 45 calls so far out of 125.000 a month that's available in the *Spark (Free)* plan. So I am nowhere near to the limit. Nor am I making outgoing requests, just Firebase Database operations.

Another strange fact is that I am unable to see output of `console.log("hello world");` from the cloud code function in the firebase console. I know the Cloud function is being called, I see that in the log.

Does it mean that the encoding is not accepted by the Firebase cloud function? This is an Omnivore API Webhook. If so, then how do I make this work if I cannot change the encoding? And if not, what is the issue?

This is the body of the Firebase cloud function:

```
admin.database().ref('/omnivoreCodes').child(req.body.name).set(req.body.id);
res.status(200).send(`success`);
```

And it's tested and works when I make a POST request via Postman.

Comment: What plan are you on? You can only access an external network, i.e. Stripe, if you have your billing configured and although you are not exceeding the quota, you must upgrade to the pay as you Blaze plan to do so.

Comment: I'm having a hard time picturing what you're doing.  How about showing some minimal working code for both the client and function sides?

Comment: @Callam: as I said, I am on Spark plan. That shouldn't affect what I am doing if I made 45/125.000 calls, that's not even 1% of the limit. Also I don't make outbound calls. Just working with the database.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson: I am just handling an incoming request and writing to database, that's all there is.

Comment: @DougStevenson Same issue here. On Spark plan.  Functions worked fine until my last deployment and am now getting this. Only changed one line of code.  Very Frustrating!

Comment: @AbnerFlores did you find a solution to this?  I have the same issue.