# How to deal with incorrect header check at Gunzip.zlibOnError on Firebase functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I have a pretty simple function on firebase, but can't figure out why I get an error for some request, or even how to debug them.

The error I get is

> incorrect header check at Gunzip.zlibOnError

In an attempt to debug it I added a simple logger first in the express pipeline:

```
const logger = async (req: any, res: any, next: any) => {
    try {
        console.log("==> Request body: ", JSON.stringify(req.body));
        console.log("==> Request headers: ", JSON.stringify(req.headers));
    }
    catch(error) {
        console.log("==> Failed to log: ", error);
    }
    next();
    return;
}
```

It seems that not even this logger code is executed, so I'm not sure where the error is. Is it in express? Is it on firebase? Or is it because I have some version issues?

*UPDATE:*

Complete log for one request:

> 8:57:27.264 PM sdkconfig Function execution started
>
> 8:57:27.268 PM sdkconfig Error: incorrect header check at Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:153:15)
>
> 8:57:27.268 PM sdkconfig Function execution took 4 ms, finished with status code: 400

this is even though my `logger` is the first thing in the express pipeline. So it seems like the request doesn't even reach express.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the complete, minimal code that anyone can use to reproduce the problem, including the steps you take to invoke the function.

Comment: @DougStevenson I would definitely do that if I could. But since I don't know what is causing the problem that is hard to do. As I said, the above logger is the first thing in the express pipeline, but don't get anything logged for any of those requests. What I do ask is tips on next step to debug this kind of issue on firebase  and/or express.

Comment: hm, maybe this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46384133/firebase-cloud-functions-incorrect-header-check. Looks like this has happened before and you've also commented on that one @DougStevenson

Comment: One more clarification. I fail to reproduce the error myself, I only see it when I get the call from some of the devices calling the function, but not all devices.

Comment: @DougStevenson updated the question with some more info.

Comment: Are you deploying this with the Firebase CLI or gcloud?  (And if gcloud, why is this tagged firebase?)

Comment: deploying with firebase cli. I think we have found what is causing the problem. We have an unorthodox client that gzip THAN encrypt the data (don't ask me why), but still uses the gzip header. That won't work since it will not be proper gzip data after the encryption. Is there a way I can intercept the request when the gzip fails? As it is now it looks like my code is never executed and the request is stopped by the hosting environment.